# Why does BorderLayout crop out JSlider on JFrame

Tags: java, graphics, fullscreen, jframe

I have some working code with a small circle randomly appearing around a large circle in the middle, kinda like planets. I have implemented a JSlider that controls the speed of the small ball moving around, and has set it's location to `BorderLayout.SOUTH`.  The problem is that you can't see the slider when you run. You have to click fullscreen for it to appear. I have a windows computer and I know  that it is blocked by the toolbar, but I kinda don't want to move it. Is there a way to use Java and set it to fullscreen without doing it manually? Here is my code:

```
     package com.company;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main extends JPanel {



       private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        private static int random = 11;
        private static JSlider timeController = new JSlider(1000, 3000, 3000);
        private static Runnable number = () -> random = (int) (Math.random() * 110) + 1;

        private static ScheduledExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            number = () -> random = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
            executor1.scheduleWithFixedDelay(number, 0, timeController.getValue(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            frame.getContentPane().add(new Main());
            frame.setSize(2000, 1080);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_HORIZ);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setResizable(true);
            timeController.setBackground(Color.RED);

            timeController.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.ITALIC, 10));
            timeController.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
            timeController.setMajorTickSpacing(100);
            timeController.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
            timeController.setPaintTicks(true);
            timeController.setPaintLabels(true);
            timeController.addChangeListener(e -> sliderChanged());
            frame.add(timeController, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }

        private static void sliderChanged() {
            executor1.shutdown();
            executor1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            number = () -> random = (int) (Math.random() * 110) + 1;
            executor1.scheduleWithFixedDelay(number, 0, (timeController.getValue()), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g2) {
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2;
            g.fillOval(770, 250, 400, 400);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            if (random > 0 && random <= 15) {
                g.fillOval(920, 3, 100, 100);
            } else

 if (random > 15 && random <= 20) {
            g.fillOval(920, 797, 100, 100);
        } else if (random > 20 && random <= 35) {
            g.fillOval(523, 400, 100, 100);
        } else if (random > 35 && random <= 50) {
            g.fillOval(1317, 400, 100, 100);
        } else if (random > 50 && random <= 65) {
            g.fillOval(620, 143, 100, 100);
        } else if (random > 65 && random <= 80) {
            g.fillOval(1220, 143, 100, 100);
        } else if (random > 80 && random <= 90) {
            g.fillOval(620, 657, 100, 100);
        } else if (random > 90 && random <= 100) {
            g.fillOval(1220, 657, 100, 100);
        }
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of changing a question after an answer has been posted i would suggest that you ask a second question instead, [see Edit](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/179018/revisions) and [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/answers-changed-scope-of-question-rephrase-or-reask)

Comment: Have you tried adding all the components *before* you make the frame visible?